# Displaying table data from page using find_element_by_xpath (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, html-table

I am trying to figure out how to use the `find_element_by_xpath()` to find table elements on a page and display or print them.

Here is the snippet of the page info:

```
<tbody id="listContainer_databody">  
            <tr id="listContainer_row:0" class=""><th  scope="row" class="" valign="top"></th>
                <td  class="" valign="top">2012Fall-ACC1300-01</td>
                     <td  class="" valign="top">INTRO TO FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING</td>
                     <td  class="" valign="top">3/2/12 1:03 PM</td>
                     <td  class="" valign="top">jdoe</td>
                     <td  class="" valign="top">Jane Doe</td>
                     <td  class="" valign="top">2012Fall_CRS</td>
            </tr>
```

I could not find anything that shows how to actually do this so I can get a print out like this:

```
                     2012Fall-ACC1300-01
                     INTRO TO FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING
                     3/2/12 1:03 PM
                     jdoe
                     Jane Doe
                     2012Fall_CRS
```

The code I have so far in Python does not give me an error but I do not seem to be able to display the results I want or at least a bit of information:

```
try:
xpath = '//*[@id="listContainer_databody"]'
    xpath2 = '//*[@id="listContainer_row:0"]/td[2]' 
results = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2)
print results.get_attribute('td[2]')

except NoSuchElementException:
 assert 0, "can't find xpath"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath (`xpath2`) is not correct. You should use `'//*[@id="listContainer_row:0"]/td'` as an xpath, which will return a list of web elements. You probably need to use `find_elements_by_xpath`, iterate the web elements and use the `get_text()` method on each of theM.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just noticed your response after posting my. We are on the same page. Thanks for your help! Using `get_text()` did not work but `i.text` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! The code below:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="listContainer_row:0"]/td'
for i in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
    print (i.text)
```

Produced the following results:

```
                 2012Fall-ACC1300-01
                 INTRO TO FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING
                 3/2/12 1:03 PM
                 jdoe
                 Jane Doe
                 2012Fall_CRS
```

The [documentation HERE](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html) helped!